# Want to change the sequence/order of my classes & trainers widget on homepage (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to change the sequence / order of the different group lessons (Onze groepslessen) and trainers (Onze instructeurs) on my homepage. In the wordpress back end I do not see a possiblity to do this.

For example: I want to show Bodypump first instead of Yoga.
You can find my website here: http://test.healthclubone.nl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are posts look for a wp post order plugin.

Here's a resource for plugins, https://perishablepress.com/6-ways-to-customize-wordpress-post-order/

You could also modify the code, have a look at the wp codex for all available options:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks. After trying several plugin I found one that works for my theme: https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/